# To include a particular set of punctuation symbols in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python code to generate random password such as

```
def password_random_generator():
    min_char = 8
    max_char = 12
    all_char = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + 
               string.punctuation + string.digits
    password = "".join(random.choice(all_char) for x in 
               range(random.randint(min_char, max_char)))
    return password
```

what is the way I can include only particular set of punctuation instead of all the punctuation in python3?

Comment: what is the subset that you want?

Comment: the string "constants" are just predefined strings. you can make/use your own `myspecialchars = '!"§$'` and use that. - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html for what each string entails.

Comment: @RBalasubramanian: I want to include only few punctuation while generating random password

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Thank you...it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added parameter to your function to specify only your desired punctuation:

```
import string, random

def password_random_generator(my_punctuation=string.punctuation):
    min_char = 8
    max_char = 12
    all_char = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + \
               my_punctuation + string.digits
    password = "".join(random.choice(all_char) for x in
               range(random.randint(min_char, max_char)))
    return password

print(password_random_generator('<=>'))
```

Output (for example):

> 04es=KDC

Comment: Thank you for the info...SO you are passing the punctuation set in  the print statement. As I am using this method in different class so do I have to give the set everytime?

Comment: @Roxy No, I'm passing new punctuation as parameter of `password_random_generator` function. You can see my_punctuation parameter there.